# Replace conditional logic with strategy pattern

Tags: scala, strategy-pattern, multikey

I have a long conditional logic.Wanted to have an efficient way to do so.

```
(city, country) match {

("USA","NewYork") => someVal=1.0
("USA","SomeOther")=> someVal =2.0
....
}
```

I have this look-up logic inside of loop, how do I cleanly do it.May be a multi-key map or stategy pattern in Scala

Comment: You can construct a `Map[String, Float]` where, for example, `usa_newyork` is the key and 1.0 is the value, and then `map.get(s"$country_city")`

Answer (score 1):

You have some of ways of doing it. Besides the one use used you can try also:

```
val map1: Map[(String, String), Double]
map1((country, city)): Double // or
map1.get((country, city)): Option[Double]
```

or

```
val map2: Map[String, Map[String, Double]]
map2(country)(city): Double
map2.get(country).flatMap(_.get(city)): Option[Double]
```

Which one is faster? I don't know. You would have to make the benchmarks for your use case. `Map` is probably faster than `match` but without benchmarks nobody can tell how much. Which map is faster? `map1` or `map2`? We might guess but without benchmarks for your use cases, it's just guessing.

Unfortunately, until you run it in something like [JMH](https://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/) and compare the results, it might be just results for cold JVM.

And, as long as you use `String` as keys, it would be difficult to suggest some solution like `Strategy` or anything from GoF, etc, because they rely on either being able to add some property/method to the class to make computation cheaper and/or on the fact that there is finite number of possibilities which unlocks some optimizations.

Comment: So,to implement a design pattern from GOF...I can make these into class or case class ..how does a look-up needs to be designed ?

Comment: If cities and countries were separate classes? You would have a lot of options. Too many to put it in one SO answer.

Comment: cities and countries as string fields in same class.